# How to invoke a method of class from interface return type object using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I’m learning a problem statement of my work project.

```
interface performable{
 public void perform();
}

class searchOne implements performable{

    public void perform(){
        Sysout("from searchOne)
    }

    public static Performable from(){
        return new searchOne();
    }

}
class searchTwo implements performable{
    
    public void perform(){
        Sysout("from searchtwo)
    }

    public static Performable from(){
        return new searchOne();
    }

}
class mainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new mainClass().triesTo(searchOne.from,searchTwo.from)
    }
    
    triesTo(Performable...perform){
        //parameters inside tries two return two performable object
        for(Performable per:perform){
        }
    }

}
```

I understand that triesTo args return performable var arg type object. My question here is with the type of performable object how to iterate and invoke appropriate implementation class method using java reflection. To also learn further under which concept or design pattern these type of scenarios come under.

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection here?

Comment: So without reflection how do to invoke perform method from searchOne class followed by searchTwo

Comment: Well, you already have the `for` loop.  All you really need is `for (Performable per: perform) { per.perform(); }`.  You just call it like any other method.

Comment: Does this belong to any of design pattern?

Comment: Not really.  The use of the interface is polymorphism, but...it's just a method call.

Comment: What do you mean with “I understand that triesTo returns performable var arg type object”? Your `triesTo` has no return type declaration nor any `return` statement.

Comment: Holger its a type miss, triesTo parameter returns performable type objects